# Помогите написать регулярное выражение для слова из 3х букв

Tags: php

Мне необходимо проверить строку на валидность с помощью рег. выражения.

Строка может быть такого вида:

```
с
сш
сша
```

Все три варианта вверху валидные. Остальные варианты должны быть не валидными. то есть:

```
ша
са
а
```

не валидны.

Каким должно быть рег. выражение?

```
if(preg_match("", $string))
{
 echo "boom!";
}
```

Comment: Если уж совсем просто то - с|сш|сша

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используя незахватывающие группы `(?:)` с квантификатором необязательности(0 или 1) `?`:

`/^с(?:ш(?:а)?)?$/`

[Демонстрация](https://3v4l.org/oKaDT)

Comment: https://regexr.com на этом сайте ваш пример не матчится.

Comment: https://regexr.com/3v0j2

Comment: Значит еще нужны флаги? или их указывать ненадо? В скрипте работает без, а на том сайте ваш пример с флагами

Comment: Флаг m(ultiline) нужен для этой тестилки многострочной. Я же специально демонстрацию добавил для php строк.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо большое! Все работает!